# checksum phase in the I2C model shown bellow for si7021

Tags: embedded

in the diagram shown bellow taken from Si7021 sensor datasheet shon bellow page 20.

we have a checksum stage.

I cant see where the LS Byte ends and where the checksum starts? the while 10 step is not clear to me with regarding of what going after what?

Thanks.

https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/Si7021-A20.pdf

[image]

Comment: From the datasheet: "Optionally, a checksum byte can be returned from the slave for use in checking for transmission errors. The checksum byte will follow the least significant measurement byte if it is acknowledged by the master. The checksum byte is not returned if the master “not acknowledges” the least significant measurement byte."

Comment: So if we aprove  checksum byte. then how is the diagram going to look like the SLAVE will send LS Byte and checksum byte one after the other?

Comment: If you want the checksum, then you need to ACK the LSB to tell the slave to continue sending. If you don't want the checksum, you NACK the LSB to tell the slave to stop.

Comment: Hello Mat thanks for the great answer.
I have another point i wanted to ask about, and thats about the ACK's from the slave. 
What do we do if instead of recieving ACK from the slave we recieve NACK.
We just send the command again?

Answer (score 0):

Any standard interface allows you to define how many bytes you wish to receive via I2C using the standard protocol for reading. You can choose yourself how many bytes you want to receive. You either read the two result bytes only, or three bytes if you want the checksum.

The difference is how many bytes to receive so that MCU sends ACK to continue transfer, before the last requested byte is transferred and commanding the MCU to send NAK and stop condition.